# Applying gravity on free falling bodies?

Tags: java, libgdx, gravity

I am trying to make something like [this](http://www.design-simulation.com/IP/simulationlibrary/flashsimulations/AirResistance01.swf) in libgdx, but I want the user to be able to set the mass and area of the objects, and then show them that no matter the mass or area the two objects will still fall at the same time (if there is no force resistance) because of gravity. So what is the formula for that? and just like on the link, I also want to calculate the time it takes to fall and the maximum speed in m/sec.

Comment: The link displays a blank page..

Comment: if you open it on a different tab yes, try reloading the page.

Comment: Here's what you want https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-calculation-for-gravity-in-a-vacuum

Comment: So after calculating the force, how do I apply it? position.x -= force every second? I also taught that the force increases as time goes by, and the altitude? because the higher then higher it takes to hit the ground thus the maximum force will be higher depending on the altitude that it was dropped.

Comment: add the calculated acceleration (this depends on the air resistance you set with the mass) to the velocity position.y velocity divided by seconds/libgdxframe

Comment: like http://codepen.io/donovanh/pen/FHtwk

Comment: So for example the calculated force of 2 objects are (33370*10^-11 N) then I will apply it like this: float velocity = 0; then velocity += 33370*10^-11 * deltaTime; then position.y -= velocity. What I did to the velocity is basically add 33370*10^-11 every second. Is this correct?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming.